# WordPress wpdb trying to select data DISTINCT yet still display duplicated results

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, distinct

I have a PHP code with MySQL using WordPress that includes a dropdown list  where the system fetch the database and display the data in the dropdown list, in the database there are some rows that are duplicated.

I need to select the data without duplication so i used this query but it did not work .

```
 $query_site_location =$wpdb->get_results("select DISTINCT 
                      l.siteID,
                      l.locationName, 
                      l.ownerID, 
                      l.stationID,
                      o.ownerNAME,
                      t.stationName,
                      n.inspectionDate,
                      s.soldierID
                       from army_site_location l
                       LEFT  
                       JOIN owner_site o
                       on l.ownerID = o.ownerID
                       LEFT  
                       JOIN station_type t
                       on l.stationID = t.stationID
                       LEFT  
                       JOIN inspection_info n
                       on l.siteID = n.siteID
                       LEFT  
                       JOIN soldier s
                       on n.soldierID = s.soldierID");

                      foreach($query_site_location as $row)
                      {                                             

echo "<option id = '".$row ->ownerNAME."' name = '".$row ->stationName."' id2 = '".$row ->ownerID."' name2 = '".$row ->stationID."' id3 = '".$row ->soldierName."' name3 = '".$row ->soldierID."' '".$row ->inspectionDate."'  '".$row ->locationName."'>".$row->locationName."</option>";
```

Comment: With respect, *it did not work* is useless as a problem statement on Stack Overflow. It could mean anything from "my server caught fire" to "I got duplicate results even when I thought I shouldn't"  Please [edit] your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer :

```
 $query_site_location =$wpdb->get_results("Select DISTINCT
                      l.locationName,
                      e.soldierID,
                      e.soldierName,
                      i.inspectionID,
                      i.inspectionDate
                      FROM
                      army_site_location l 
                      JOIN inspection_site s
                      ON
                      s.siteID = l.siteID
                     JOIN inspection_info i 
                     ON
                     i.inspectionID = s.inspectionID
                     JOIN soldier e 
                     ON
                     e.soldierID = i.soldierID");

                     echo $query_site_location;

                      foreach($query_site_location as $row)
                      {




                       // echo "<option id = '".$row ->ownerNAME."' name = '".$row ->stationName."' id2 = '".$row ->ownerID."' name2 = '".$row ->stationID."' '".$row ->locationName."'>".$row->locationName."</option>";

echo "<option id = '".$row ->soldierName."' name = '".$row ->inspectionDate."' id2 = '".$row ->soldierID."' name2 = '".$row ->inspectionID."' '".$row ->locationName."'>".$row->locationName."</option>";



                      }
```